# How to make a variable as hyperlink in azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use a variable(with URL) to create a hyperlink in azure logic apps designer. I found a roundabout, but would like to know if that is the exact way of doing things?

I'm doing it observing the hyperlink option provided while creating task(an ADO workitem creation action). The option for creating hyperlink takes only text fields can't input variables in there. So I observed the change in code and tried embedding it manually(in code with href tag)

```
Additional Details:<br>\n</strong>Id:@{triggerBody()?['data']?['context']?['id']}<br>\nResource Id: @{triggerBody()?['data']?['context']?['resourceId']}<br>\nSubs Id: @{triggerBody()?['data']?['context']?['subscriptionId']}<br>\nExternal Link: <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a> <br>\nHyperlink: <a href=@{triggerBody()?['data']?['context']?['resourceURL']}>Variable with Link</a></p>",
```

It works, but I must make any further updates to the logic app only through code not through the UI designer because if use the designer to change things, the hyperlink created in code is messed up.

And this is how it shows up when I follow the approach mentioned, Hyperlink is the one where I embedded a variable(resourceURL) into a href tag in code view

[image: Designer View]

All this works, but my complaint is I must update logic app only by code if I follow this approach.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the variable and define the content that you want to specify in the description property of your Create a work item action.
For any connector if you have HTML tags as the text then you should always create the variable first and then leverage the same in your actions.

When you specify the variable inside the Description and the HTML tags rendering will automatically taken care for you.

[image]

Comment: I am running into an issue with this method. I am trying to send an email with this variable as a clickable link, which will send them to the website. It is showing clickable text and when I hover the text it shows the proper link, however it will not open the page or new tab.